# Multi select List Box with Table inside and select multiple row

Tags: jquery, html, css, yui

[image]

I know how to make a multi select list box. But my project requirement is to have a multi list box only but the box should contain a tabular structure with multiple rows inside. If any column is clicked it should select all the rows. Pictorial representation as attached.

Comment: Please share the code you use, and show us what you've tried so far, and where you get stucked...

Comment: it will be a  multi column combo box. I cannot get started because I cannot imagine how to put a table inside a select tag, apart from jquery or yui included.